# Hash table stored in *vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have to create a hash table in C++ using an vector of an abstract data type and I'm having trouble reading and writing to the vector.

Here is the header file showing the declaration:

```
#ifndef ASSIGNMENT8_H
#define ASSIGNMENT8_H
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Entry {
    std::string key;
    std::string description;
    Entry() { key = "---"; }
};

class HT {
    private:
        std::vector<Entry>* hTable;
        int table_size;
        int item_count;
        int hashing(const std::string&);
    public:
        HT();
        HT(int size);
        ~HT();
        bool insert(const Entry& e);
        int search(const std::string& key);
        bool remove(const std::string& s);
        void print();
};

#endif
```

And here's my display function showing an example of how I'm trying to access the data in the vector:

```
void HT::print()
{
  cout << "----Hash Table----" << endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < table_size; i++)
  {
      cout << hTable[i].key << " " << hTable[i].description << endl;
  }
  cout << endl << "------------------" << endl;
}
```

I always get the following error message: 
assignment8.cc:138:25: error: ‘class std::vector’ has no member named ‘key’

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What is in assignment8.cc:138:25? Why is `hTable` a pointer? `hTable[i]` is the same as `*(hTable + i)`. It returns a vector. You could `(*hTable)[i]`.

Comment: That's a code smell. You should ask yourself why is it a pointer.

Comment: This is actually the first time I've heard of a code smell, had to look it up. It's definitely something I'll keep in mind for the future. The structure and class were actually both written by my professor so I probably would have tried to use something simpler I'm more familiar with like a 2D array if I had had the freedom to do so